# App crashing after creating new activity

Tags: android

So I made a new activity class:

```
public class TutorialActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tutorial, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And inside a thread I try to open it:

```
public void run() {
            if(newGame) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this.activity, TutorialActivity.class);
                this.activity.startActivity(intent);
            }

            while(inGame) {
                try {
                    this.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

I see the new activity because I see the text I set in it but then it instantly crashes. So it does load the activity but then something happens and it just crashes.

Log:

```
08-29 23:49:45.242: D/AndroidRuntime(21100): Shutting down VM
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100): Process: com.example.trollacademy, PID: 21100
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.trollacademy/com.example.trollacademy.MainActivity}: android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.trollacademy/com.example.trollacademy.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onStop()
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3855)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3908)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:177)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100): Caused by: android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.trollacademy/com.example.trollacademy.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onStop()
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6495)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3852)
08-29 23:49:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(21100):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace that appears in logcat.

Comment: where is ur crash log?

Comment: Apologies new to android, I think thats all the log what I just posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activity from which you call the new "TutorialActivity" has a wrong implementation of the method `onStop()`.

The methods with tag `@Override` should always come with a super call, so your onStop method should look somethng like:

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop(); // THIS LINE IS MISSING ON YOUR CODE

    //Other things you want to do.
}
```

You didn't post this part of the code of your other activity, but is probably that. You could also edit your question and add this part of the code to help others.

Comment: This is the answer thanks! I overrode it and never added this part thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To create new activity, you must create new class and defined it in androidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.trollacademy/com.example.trollacademy.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onStop()

if u override onStop, u should call super.onStop().
I dont know which IDE u use,but if the IDE give u a red line, u should find the reason why it is red,and fix it.

Hope fun